YouTube Analytics API returns Forbidden error. How can I get analytics data with Viewer permission?
Another team owns a YouTube channel and I was invited as Viewer.
I can check analytics data through YouTube Studio.
Now I am struggling to download the data by using YouTube Analytics API.
The owner team provided me Client ID and Secret by enabling YouTube related APIs.
However I cannot access their channel data with Forbidden error.
I tried to download with following python code, but it returns "Forbidden"
Any suggestion/solution to download analytics data with Viewer permission?
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly']
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtubeAnalytics'
API_VERSION = 'v2'
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = 'client_secret.json'

def get_service():
  flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
  credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=8888)
  return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials = credentials)

def execute_api_request(client_library_function, **kwargs):
  response = client_library_function(
    **kwargs
  ).execute()
  print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'

  youtubeAnalytics = get_service()

  execute_api_request(
      youtubeAnalytics.reports().query,
      ids='channel==UCxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      startDate='2024-12-01',
      endDate='2024-12-10',
      metrics='estimatedMinutesWatched,views,likes,subscribersGained',
      dimensions='day',
      sort='day'
  )

